# Customization of quick search

Tags: magento2.3, search, php-7, catalogsearch-fulltext

My Magento version is 2.3 community, What I want to know is how can i detect a full text search not a combined one, Example - when I search the word Apollo plus I want it to show results only for Apollo plus but not for other Apollo rangers.

Comment: are you using elasticsearch as search engine?

Comment: NO not elasticsearch I'm using Mysql

Comment: I see. so what I think you are asking for is how to perform 'exact matches' and not just partial ones, is that correct?

Comment: Yes Probably that I want

Comment: https://www.cavendishdevereonline.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=Apollo+Plus+Tortilla
 I want to remove this plus mark in end of the URL how to do this